# Understanding passing data from a page to a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have been struggling with how to pass data between a page and a UserControl and could use some clarification as to what I may be doing incorrectly. I know that the UserControl is working if I remove the data part of the code and replace it with just TextBlocks.

I do know that the NetWorth is being displayed, but just can't see why the `List<Account>` isn't passed on. I don't know what it is I am doing wrong here.

### PanelNavigation.xaml

```xaml
        <!-- Navigation Section -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0.333,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <UserControls:NavigationPanel DataContext="{Binding Accounts}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- Networth Panel -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Height="40">
            <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuBarBrush}" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}">
                <Grid Margin="5,5,10,5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Margin="10,1,10,1" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FF346C9C" Text="Net Worth" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Column="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding NetWorth, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyConverter}}"
                               Foreground="{Binding NetWorth, Converter={StaticResource ChangeColor}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

### PanelNavigation.xaml.cs

```cs
using APTest.ViewModels;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace APTest.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PanelNavigation.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PanelNavigation : Page
    {
        public PanelNavigation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new VMNavigationPanel(this);

        }
    }
}
```

### NavigationPanel.xaml

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="APTest.UserControls.NavigationPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:APTest.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="DataTest" ItemsSource ="{Binding Accounts}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalBalance}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

### NavigationPanel.xaml.cs

```xaml
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace APTest.UserControls
{
    public partial class NavigationPanel : UserControl
    {
        public NavigationPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

and lastly

### VMNavigationPanel.cs

```cs
using AccountingPlus.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace APTest.ViewModels
{
    class VMNavigationPanel  : BaseViewModel
    {
        private Page mPage;
        private ObservableCollection<Account> accounts;
        public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts {
            get => accounts;
            set {
                accounts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double NetWorth { get; set; } = 127492.30;

        public VMNavigationPanel(Page page)
        {
            mPage = page;

            Accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();

            Account test = new Account();
            test.TotalBalance = 100234.23;

            Accounts.Add(test);
        }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public double TotalBalance {get; set;}
    }
}
```

### BaseViewModel.cs

```cs
using PropertyChanged;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace APTest
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (Sender, e) => { };

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Itemssource should bind Accounts. Observablecollection instead of list. Always implement inotifypropertychanged on a viewmodel and raise propertychanged in setters. Don't pass ui elements like a page into a viewmodel.

Comment: Frames and pages come with overheads if you don't need forward backward navigation like a wizard. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: @Andy Can you explain what you mean by passing UI Elements like a page into a ViewModel? I have a page with a UIControl, that is embedded into the mainWindow via a <Frame> still debating whether that is a good thing or not.

As for the INotifyPropertyChanged, I actually had that, but removed it for testing and placing it back made no difference and the ObservableCollection made no difference.

Comment: @AndyAnd as I am still learning, what do you recommend instead of a frame/page then. To give an example of what I am trying to achieve. Think of a side navigation with a list of information and links. These links can then open up a further content into a main content section.

I know I need to use a frame here, as I don't see any other way to make changes to that main content area, and that page has to have UserControls.

Comment: Vmnavigationpanel is a viewmodel. It's supposed to work totally independent of ui and a page is ui. I put a link in my comment above. It wasn't random. Read it. And then google viewmodel first. Take the word frame. Take the word page. Put them in a box. Close the lid.. And think contentcontrol and usercontrol. Datatemplate with datatype defining what ui you get for a viewmodel.

Comment: @Andy I understand that it wasn't there randomly and I have read it, all I am trying to do is reduce the amount of data that is loaded when a page is switched in and out. Anyway, that is neither here nor there, this still doesn't work. Even without it being a Page!

Comment: Did you also make the 4 other changes?

Comment: Yes those changes had been made, the post has also been updated to reflect those changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221292/discussion-between-andrew-scott-and-andy).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need property in your model to bind the object. You cannot bind a field.

So that your Account class should be like that:

```
public class Account
{
    public double TotalBalance { get; set; }

}
```

Also keep that in mind, to update UI in WPF we need to use ObservableCollections. For example if you clicked a button and you added an item to your Accounts collection then item'll be in your collection but in the UI you won't see the updated result if you use List collections that's why you need to use ObservableCollections.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1

Another thing is your binding is misspelled. In your NavigationPanel.xaml it should TotalBalance.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalBalnce}" />
```

Here is the working code of your View Model:

I also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface for you but haven't used with any other properties.

```
class VMNavigationPanel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged<T>(ref T property, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        property = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private Page mPage;

    public double NetWorth { get; set; } = 127492.30;

    private ObservableCollection<Account> accounts;
    public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts
    {
        get => accounts;
        set
        {
            accounts = value;
        }
    }

    public VMNavigationPanel(Page page)
    {
        mPage = page;

        Accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();

        Account test = new Account();
        test.TotalBalance = 100234.23;

        Accounts.Add(test);
    }

}

public class Account
{
    public double TotalBalance { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Those changes had already been made, the Property Change is in a base class, that I had omitted at first, but makes no difference. I have reflected the post with the current changes as suggested and back to what I had before I started fiddling.

There isn't anything that you aren't doing, that I wasn't the only thing I did differently and changed to what you had, was the get had a condition if its was null to create the collection. Instead of having it in the constructor. I moved to the constructor with no difference.